# Creating a dynamic Image on Mouse Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, jquery-hover

I want to create an Image when the users hovers over a certain thing. I want some data on the image which I am creating dynamically through javascript. Attaching the image of what I need to do here,...[image]

I want the Target Image to be dispayed on hover. Any idea how can I proceed with?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for tooltip with image. Try these examples.

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/

http://calebjacob.com/tooltipster/

http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/

http://cssglobe.com/easiest-tooltip-and-image-preview-using-jquery/

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/

http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/tools/jquery-tooltip-scripts/

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any existing code?

Also you can try the

```
:hover
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp and

```
:after
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp
and the content attribute

Answer (score 0):

You can try using jQuery's "hover" method and capture the mouse position from the callback function's event parameter. Then append a new absolutely positioned div and style it with the top and left parameter positions you acquired from the mouse position. Add any info that you need to display on the popup and append it to the newly created div.

Comment: Is there any example available online?

Comment: Plenty. And CharmingaD just posted some of them.

Answer (score 0):

function goes in javascript:

```
function showIt(imgsrc)
{
document.getElementById('imageshow').src=imgsrc;
document.getElementById('imageshow').style.display='block';
}

function hideIt()
{
document.getElementById('imageshow').style.display='none';
}
```